# Automorphisms of ($\omega, *$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, model-theory

I'm trying to find the onto, operation preserving automorphisms of ($\omega, *$), where $*$ is normal multiplication. I have only been able to think of the identity automorphism. Are there others? I know no automorphism will have the form $$f(x) = nx, n \in \omega$$ $$g(x) = x + n, n\in \omega$$ because such functions are not orperation preserving.

Moreover, if there is a 2nd automorphism, will functions similar to it be useful for constructing isomorphisms to  ($\omega, *$)?

Comment: What is $\omega$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde The set of natural numbers.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde $\omega = \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Every automorphism is onto (by definition), and there are already no order-preserving automorphisms of $\omega$ other than the identity, so multiplication has nothing to do with it. On the other hand, there are lots of (non-order-preserving) automorphisms of $(\omega,*)$ coming from permuting the primes. Also, I'm confused by your examples: both $f$ and $g$ are order-preserving maps (when $n>1$). But they fail to be automorphisms, since they are not onto and they do not preserve $*$ (when $n>1$).

Comment: With automorphism you mean an order preserving bijection also preserving multiplication? If so, you can check: What is the image of the minimal element of $\Bbb N$? The image of the second smallest, third smallest etc

Comment: @AlexKruckman sorry, I meant operation preserving. How would permitting primes help me?

Comment: That was a typo - I meant permuting the primes.

Comment: @AlexKruckman by permuting the primes in a mapping, what do you mean? They also preserve multiplication? Something like $\phi(x) = 2^x5^x7^x...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P$ be the set of prime numbers. I'll leave it to you to show that if $\sigma$ is an automorphism of $(\omega,*)$, then $\sigma$ fixes $0$ and $1$ and restricts to a bijection $P\to P$.

Conversely, given any bijection $\tau\colon P\to P$, $\tau$ extends to a unique automorphism $\sigma$ by sending $0$ to $0$, $1$ to $1$, and acting on every other number according to its prime factorization: $$\sigma(p_1^{n_1}\dots p_k^{n_k})=\tau(p_1)^{n_1}\dots\tau(p_k)^{n_k}. $$

Since there are (countably) infinitely many primes, this shows that there are continuum many automorphisms of $(\omega,*)$.